# Incorrect way to compare variable strings?

Tags: php, html

I thought checking that two variables are the same, and echoing out a message depending on the specified condition worked this way. I have to be wrong somewhere though. This is just one test condition of a draw if both variables are the same rock/rock, paper/paper, etc... I typed it in to see if this would even work.

PHP CODE

```
  <?php
  $items = Array('rock','paper','scissors');
  $randomChoice = $items[array_rand($items)];
  $choice = $_POST['choice'];

  if ($choice == $randomChoice) {
    echo "Its a draw!";
  } else {
     header('Location: index.php');
}
```

HTML CODE

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Rock! Paper! Scissors</h3>
    <form action="handle.php" method="POST">
      <p>Chose one of the options</p>
    <select name="choice" required>
      <option value="Rock">Rock</option>
      <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
      <option value="Scissors">Scissors</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit my choice">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"Rock" != "rock"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because your option value begins with a capital letter, but items in the array begin with a lower case.

So you decide what you want to change ... I'd rather have everything in lower case:

```
<select name="choice" required>
  <option value="rock">Rock</option> <!-- lower case!-->
  <option value="paper">Paper</option>
  <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should validate the user-supplied data.

```
$items = array('rock','paper','scissors');
$choice = array_key_exists('choice', $_POST) ? strtolower($_POST['choice']) : null;
if (!in_array($choice, $items, true)) {
   die('Show an error message or do something here');
}
```

The above will ensure the choice value is supplied in the `$_POST` and enforce a lowercase value, otherwise set the `$choice` variable to `null`.
Then validate that the supplied value is one of the values in the `$items` array.

if you want case-insensitive comparisons, you can use [`strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

```
strcasecmp($choice, $randomChoice) === 0
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/IOSqC

```
  $items = array('rock','paper','scissors');
  $randomChoice = $items[0];
  $choice = 'Rock';

  if (strcasecmp($choice, $randomChoice) === 0) {
     echo "Its a draw!";
  } else {
     echo $randomChoice;
  }
```

Result:

```
"Its a draw!"
```

---

Alternatively you can change your select values to match the php casing.

---

References:

- [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)
- [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

Comment: I would think twice before implementing case-insensitive string comparison here. You see, making a form, he made an API with either rock, paper or scissors value. It's like enumeration, just one of the possibilities. It's reasonable to force one string style to that, as it makes it clear it's a choice, not a text input.